# Change the size of the form element for content title

Tags: nodes

I could have sworn that when we created our content type, we could select the size of the textfield for the title. I am unable to find that now as I'm in "Manage Fields" and the edit link that's available for other fields is not there for the title field. It says only in field type "Node module element". I even tried looking through our database to see if there was a place where this was set and I couldn't find anything. Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the options of choosing your title field lengths in standard D7. 
However, there is a module that lets you change that:

https://drupal.org/project/title_field_ui

The only problem is, that the module is only in alpha and not widely used. On the other hand, the module author is very reputable, so I'd give it a try.

Other solutions have been discussed before:
[Change / Increase the node title length](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21895/change-increase-the-node-title-length)

Comment: In Drupal 8+, this functionality has been added to core!